# correct way to debug npm packages in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

I have a rather unusual demand, where I want to debug the npm package code and not the application code.

I want to put a breakpoint on package code in chrome DevTools, what should be the correct way to do it?
How exactly should I bring a script which comes somewhere under "node modules" into Chrome DevTools sources tab so that I can debug it?

I have tried using npm link and adding the script to the "assets" section under options in build, but it didn't work for me. I can see the github repository using the repository field in package.json.

Comment: If you got to the function that is part of the `node_modules` and press F11 , the devTools should navigate you the the internals of the package. Keep in mind that the code that you will see when doing so most-likely will be unreadable, as it will be already processed somehow (from the building pipeline of the library itself). If you want to debug readable code than you should clone the node-package from github, put the code inside your project, and start refering that code inside your project.

Comment: Thanks 
by inside, do you mean inside source? I notice many npm packages "show up" in the node_modules ? How exactly do they arrive there?

Comment: If this question is not answered or closed, I will try to add full answer with example to your question latter tonight or tomorrow, but by inside i mean copy the library's source somewhere inside your project folder. Also if the library you are trying to debug has some peer dependencies, you will have to add them to your `package.json`

Comment: Thanks, this should fix my issue for now. I am still curious to learn your answer.